In Airflow how to avoid a DAG to run a child DAG which is disabled in the Airflow UI?
I was told to disable the dbt DAG in Airflow, which I did, but the dbt DAG in my case is called by a parent "main" DAG, which calls an "extract" DAG before calling the dbt one.
I disabled the dbt dag in the Airflow UI, but the main DAG hangs with this message:

[2024-06-14, 04:41:42 UTC] {trigger_dagrun.py:178} INFO - Waiting for extract on 2024-06-13T18:03:09.514547+00:00 to become allowed state ['success'] ...


[2024-06-14, 04:42:03 UTC] {local_task_job.py:211} WARNING - State of this instance has been externally set to failed. Terminating instance.

I had to manually mark the main DAG as failed.
I'm looking to tell the main DAG to skip calling a DAG in the chain if is disabled in the UI.

This is the main DAG code:
    # Default settings applied to all tasks
    default_args={
        "owner":"airflow",
        "retries": 0,
        "retry_delay": timedelta(minutes=5),
        "start_date": datetime(2021, 12, 1),
        "catchup": False,
        'on_failure_callback': on_failure_callback,
    }
    
    @dag(
        start_date=datetime(2019, 1, 1),
        max_active_runs=1,
        schedule_interval=schedule(daily_schedule), # Run at 5:00am MST
        default_args=default_args,
        catchup=False,
        concurrency=4,
        tags=['extract', 'main']
    )
    def main():
        with TaskGroup(group_id='extract') as extract:
            TriggerDagRunOperator(
                task_id='extract',
                trigger_dag_id='extract',
                wait_for_completion=True,
                trigger_rule="all_done" # Run even if previous tasks failed
            )
        
        dbt = TriggerDagRunOperator(
            task_id='dbt',
            trigger_dag_id='dbt_api_dag',
            wait_for_completion=True,
            trigger_rule="all_done" # Run even if previous tasks failed
        )
    
        extract >> dbt
    
    taskflow = main()


By the way, this is what asking Gemini returned, but I haven't tested it yet. I'll update the answer if this works.
from airflow import XCom

# Add a task before dbt_api_dag to check XCom
check_dbt_enabled = ShortCircuitOperator(
    task_id='check_dbt_enabled',
    provide_context=True,
)

def check_dbt_enabled_fn(**context):
    # Read XCom value with key indicating dbt_api_dag state (e.g., "dbt_api_enabled")
    dbt_enabled = XCom.pull(dag_id=dag.dag_id, task_ids='set_dbt_state', key='dbt_api_enabled')
    if dbt_enabled is None or dbt_enabled.lower() != "true":
        context['ti'].xcom_push(key='skip_dbt', value=True)
        return False  # Skip dbt_api_dag execution
    return True

check_dbt_enabled.python_callable = check_dbt_enabled_fn

# Modify dbt task to check XCom for skipping
dbt = TriggerDagRunOperator(
    task_id='dbt',
    trigger_dag_id='dbt_api_dag',
    wait_for_completion=True,
    trigger_rule="all_done",
    provide_context=True,
)

def dbt_with_skip(**context):
    skip_dbt = context['ti'].xcom_pull(key='skip_dbt', task_ids='check_dbt_enabled')
    if skip_dbt:
        return  # Skip dbt execution
    # Trigger dbt_api_dag normally if XCom is not set or set to "True"
    return True

dbt.python_callable = dbt_with_skip

# Update task dependencies
extract >> check_dbt_enabled >> dbt

